# Dynamic Environment Variables in Ionic - Cannot find module

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2

I am trying to find a good solution for dynamically injecting environment variables into an Ionic2 app based on a flag at runtime. For my use case, I need to support more than the default dev/prod options. (e.g. dev/test/qa/prod).

I'm largely basing my approach on the following with a few tweaks: https://github.com/gshigeto/ionic-environment-variables

The environment flag I'm setting is APP_ENV, just before the ionic command, like so:

`APP_ENV=dev ionic serve`

At build time, I am using a custom webpack.config file to replace an env.ts file with the target environment's .ts file. That looks like this:

**./config/Webpack.config**

```
var path = require('path');
var defaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

var env = process.env.APP_ENV;

if (!defaultConfig[env]) {  
    defaultConfig[env] = defaultConfig["dev"];
}

defaultConfig[env].resolve.alias = {
    "@app/env": path.resolve('./src/env/env.' + env + '.ts')
};

module.exports = function () {
  return defaultConfig;
};
```

and I'm telling ionic about my custom webpack configuration here:

**./package.json**

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

Additionally, I updated my tsconfig.json to let my compiler know how to resolve the alias:

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/env": [
        "env/env"
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I then define the environment variable files like so:

**./src/env/env.dev.ts**

```
export const ENV = {
    API_URL: "http://dev-url.com/"
}
```

**./src/env/env.test.ts**

```
export const ENV = {
    API_URL: "http://test-url.com/"
}
```

**./src/env/env.prod.ts**

```
export const ENV = {
    API_URL: "http://prod-url.com/"
}
```

I then pull in the import where I want to use the file:

**./src/app/pages/home/home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ENV } from '@app/env';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    console.log(ENV.API_URL);
  }

}
```

This is working great for dev or any other environment that I specify and the console logs out the appropriate URL.

However, when I run:

`APP_ENV=prod ionic serve --prod`,

I get the following:

```
Error: Cannot find module "@app/env"
    at Object.192 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:44:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.261 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:157:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.212 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:99:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.193 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:81:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1
```

I'm really not sure what's so different about prod than any other environment. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a way to set environment at runtime?
For i.e There is page which contains two radio button 1.Prod 2.Dev
and selecting any radio button will set that environment config at runtime.
I am finding a way how to set environment on selecting radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the @ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js it appears the format may have changed for app-scripts v3.

This v3 format expects the following at the end:

```
module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
};
```

If this formatting is the issue, maybe you could try something like the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var defaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

var env = process.env.APP_ENV ? process.env.APP_ENV : 'dev';

var devWebPackConfig = defaultConfig.dev;
devWebPackConfig.resolve.alias = {
  "@app/env": path.resolve('./src/env/env.' + env + '.ts')
};

var prodWebPackConfig = defaultConfig.prod;
prodWebPackConfig.resolve.alias = {
  "@app/env": path.resolve('./src/env/env.' + env + '.ts')
};

module.exports = {
  dev: devWebPackConfig,
  prod: prodWebPackConfig
};
```

Comment: The first one worked great! Do you mind if I edit your answer to contain the slightly modified version for other's reference?